# Saving line chart(.xlsx based) data from slide(.pptx) using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, powerpoint

I want to save the excel file(.xlsx) with data corresponding to a line chart in a powerpoint slide(.pptx) using apache poi.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [How to ask a good question](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using current `apacjhe poi 5.0.0` there is [XDDFChart.importContent](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html#importContent-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChart-) which imports the chart content from one `XDDFChart` to another. And there is [XDDFChart.getWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html#getWorkbook--) which gets the data source workbook behind that `XDDFChart`.

If the need is to extract a chart from `PowerPoint` into a `Excel` file, then the following needs to be done:

Get the `XSLFChart` from the `PowerPoint` slide show.

Get the data source workbook and the data source sheet behind that chart.

Create a `XSSFChart` in that sheet.

Import the chart content from the `XSLFChart`.

Save the workbook into a file.

Example:

Source `PowerPoint.pptx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class CreateExcelXDDFChartFromPowerPointXDDFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String powerPointPath = "./PowerPoint.pptx";
  String excelPath = "./Excel.xlsx";

  // get the PowerPoint slide show
  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(powerPointPath));
  // get first chart
  XSLFChart powerPointchart = slideShow.getCharts().get(0);

  // get data source workbook behind that chart
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = powerPointchart.getWorkbook();
  // get data source sheet
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  // create the chart in Excel
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 15, 30);
  XSSFChart excelChart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

  // get chart data from PowerPoint chart
  excelChart.importContent(powerPointchart);
 
  // Write the output to a file
  try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelPath)) {
   workbook.write(fileOut);
  }

  slideShow.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Result `Excel.xlsx`:

[image]

---

To perform the other way araound. To put a `Excel` chart into a `PowerPoint` silde show, the following needs to be done:

Get the `XSSFChart` from the sheet in given `Excel` workbook.

Create create a new `PowerPoint` slide show or open one existent.

Create a `XSLFChart` in a slide of that slide show.

Import the chart content from the `XSSFChart`.

Save the `Excel` workbook as `PowerPoint` chart's data source. For this we need [XDDFChart.saveWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html#saveWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-) which writes the given `XSSFWorkbook` as the data source of that chart into an embedded Excel file.

Example:

Given `Excel.xlsx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class CreatePowerPointXDDFChartFromExcelXDDFChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String excelPath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  String powerPointPath = "./PowerPoint.pptx";

  // get the Excel workbook
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(excelPath));
  // get first sheet
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  // get first chart in that sheet
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFChart excelChart = drawing.getCharts().get(0);

  // create new PowerPoint slide show
  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  // create new slide
  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  // create the chart
  XSLFChart powerPointchart = slideShow.createChart();
  // add chart to slide
  slide.addChart(powerPointchart, new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double(1d*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 1d*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 20d*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 15d*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER));
   
  // get chart data from Excel chart
  powerPointchart.importContent(excelChart);
  // save Excel workbook as PowerPoint chart's data source
  powerPointchart.saveWorkbook(workbook);
 
  // Write the output to a file
  try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(powerPointPath)) {
   slideShow.write(fileOut);
  }

  workbook.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }
}
```

Resultig `PowerPoint.pptx`:

[image]

Comment: Hey....tysm Alex.....can you please help me with the code for extracting and saving the excel data(into another excel file or as a csv) corresponding to an existing line chart in a powerpoint slide.

Comment: @Varun Vijayan: So exactly the other way around? See my supplements. My answer shows both ways now.

Comment: @Alex Richter Tysm man...Helped a lot...